# Data structure for analysis of relationship between rainfall and vegetation indices?

Tags: raster, r, fields-attributes

I have several hundred raster files (NDVI) of the same area dating back to the 1980’s, as well as daily rainfall observations from a nearby weather-station over the same period.  The raster files are in the same folder and named by date, YYYY-MM-DD (I can re-name these if it will simplify things).  I want to look at the relationship between rainfall and change in vegetation index over time at various points in that landscape using R, but I don’t know how to process the data efficiently.

Ideally the raster files could all be called from a single object, like a rasterstack, in which was also recorded the year and Julian day number (ie 1 to 365/6) for each image.  I could then extract information from rasters from specific time periods or from the whole series, and / or relate change in vegetation index to specific rainfall events (which data I already have in Julian day and year in a data frame).

I can bring the raster files into R, named as they are in the original folder and stored in a list object, from which I can then make a rasterstack, but this doesn’t attribute them a date.  Can I append a RAT to each raster when it is processed into the list, and automatically add year and Julian day attributes?

Can anyone suggest appropriate structures / functions to perform these tasks?

Comment: Any reason you can't store the raster file names as the list object names and query the list using `yourlist["dateString"]`?

Comment: Thanks.  I could do that. But in the end I think I'll have to make large `RasterBrick` and convert the names (which are dates) of each to a date with `as.Date( )`.  I can then extract data, and in the resulting data frames convert those dates to Julian days, or days since an origin.  I could then look at the relationship between rain events in one data frame and VI in another if both frames work on the same dating system.  Cumbersome but should work.